# Office 365 List or Library Information management policy settings file not found error

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, information-management

I am trying to access **Information management policy settings** at **List settings** of a SharePoint list  Error says "**File not found.**" I need access to that to initiate a overdue workflow.

I have activated the site policy feature and library and folder retention features in the site collection features but still getting the same error.

We recently migrated to Office 365 from SharePoint 2013. [image]

Comment: You have a correlation ID; you'll need to check error logs to figure out what happened.  Beyond that, there's not really much we can help with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there will be anything we can reliably do for this. In Office 365, we don't have access to the Correlation logs. I suggest you open a ticket at https://portal.office.com/support/support.aspx so the support staff can assist you.